# Columns on top of a background-image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a small eastern project. The website is here: [My Website](http://mimsi.dk/).

I need to make some boxes that contain a png picture on top of the background-picture like this:

[image]

I set the picture on the col, but I guess I need to make it as a background in CSS, since I cannot build something on top of an img tag:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <center><img src="https://mimsi.dk/images/logo.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Eastern"></center>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="https://mimsi.dk/images/eeg.jpg" alt="Eastern game" class="background">
        </div>
      </div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 1px solid red;">
          <h1 style="text-align: center;">FOOTER</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Instead of using the img src tag, I set this in my HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="col-md-12 bg">

.bg { 
    background-image: url("https://mimsi.dk/images/eeg.jpg");

    height: 100%; 

    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But nothing has worked out yet. How can I set the background-image, so it is not going to the header logo or footer, so I can build my 8 boxes on top?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough in my question. It was not text I need over the background-image, but a PNG picture.

Comment: Go take a coffee and a cigaret @Andrei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is a mistake in your `HTML` in this line `</div class="row">` i think you got that **you can't put class in closing `div`**

**Solution**

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgo6jhfm/7/)